# By default show first container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello friends i found a show hide div script on fiddle, this script i need to use in my project but my problem is that i want to show first container text by default currently by default it shows nothing only show on button click. Any one can help me for this, I w'll b very thanks full.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio"> 
    <button id="btn-game" data-target="game_container" class="btn btn btn-primary" type="button">Game</button>
    <button id="btn-video" data-target="video_container" class="btn btn btn-primary" type="button">Video</button>
    <button id="btn-giveaway" data-target="giveaway_container" class="btn btn btn-primary" type="button">Giveaway</button>
</div>
<div class="see se" id="game_container">
    game stuff
</div>

<div class="see" id="video_container">
    video stuff
</div>

<div class="see" id="giveaway_container">
    giveaway stuff
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.see').hide();
    $('.btn-group button').click(function(){
        var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
        $(".see").not(target).hide();
        $(target).show();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VYSXn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide all container excluding the first like below. Hope it helps.

```
$('.see').not(':first').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more efficient to do your hiding with css....that way the elements won't wait until the javascript kicks in and give you a flash where they are not hidden

CSS

```
.see{display:none}
#game_container{display:block}
```

replaces:

```
$(".see").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JS Code with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.container').not('#game_container').hide();
    $('.btn-group button').click(function(){
        var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
        $(".container").not(target).hide();
        $(target).show();
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VYSXn/274/